# Why is Differential Correction Wizard unable to download files?

Tags: shapefile, export, trimble, pathfinder

I am using a Trimble Geo7x to map debris flows, and when I attempt to run the differential correction wizard it is unable to "transfer files" and "download files." The image below displays the issue.[image]

Additionally, since I have been unable to correct the points, I have attempted to export the un-corrected data as a shapefile. This has been unsuccessful as well. The tool says that my features are unable to be exported, because they do not have positions.

I am wondering if there is anyway to fix these issues in Pathfinder Office, or is the data itself corrupted possibly due to issues with the Trimble device itself?

Comment: Please check your settings... https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127237/why-are-differential-correction-services-unable-to-transfer-files-for-a-24-hour

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me on several occasions.  Two possible explanations are:

1. As the link suggests in @Mapperz comment - the correction files are not yet available for download.  Wait and try later.
2. Sometimes I find it necessary to update the provider list and start the correction over from the beginning.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ah, this pestering problem has started again with the 'Update List' trick mentioned in my previous answer not working.

This time the solution was to:

1. Enter the web path of the un-downloadable file into a web browser.
   [image]

2.This took me to a website called Earth Scope where I was prompted to make an account.  After making the account I was able to download the correction files.

3.Finally, I was able to make the correction using the correct from downloaded file feature in Pathfinder Office.

[image]